# How to update value in MySQL when the stored version differs to the passed argument

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE table SET x = :x, y = :y, z = IF(x <> :x, NOW(), z);
```

I need to check whether value of the old `"x"` is different from the new `"x"`. I can't do that within the `IF` statement as shown above because value of `x` is already changed so it equals to the `:x`.

Basically, what I am trying to do is something like:

```
IF(oldX <> :newX) THEN NOW() ELSE NO CHANGE;
```

Is there any way how to achieve that or am I better doing this using a subquery or a variable? *I definitely prefer executing one query only.

Comment: Why do you need to only post one query.  Databases are ridiculously fast.  Just check the value with one query and if it returns a value update it.  Don't optimise too early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does *not* support the [standard](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) on this:

> The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the
>   current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result
>   is that col1 and col2 have the same value. This behavior differs from
>   standard SQL.

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
```

So, the following works in a simple [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30d24/1) in SQL Fiddle:

```
UPDATE table
    SET x = if (@x := x, :x, :x),
        y = :y,
        z = IF(x <> @x, NOW(), z);
```

It should also work if you reverse the order:

```
UPDATE table
    SET  z = IF(x <> :x, NOW(), z),
         x = :x,
         y = :y;
```

The documentation says that single table updates are "generally" processed in lexical order.